# Why Windows SmartScreen is RED on my signed installer?

Tags: windows, wix, code-signing

I have an Wix MSI installer with my app. the MSI is signed with certificate.

But when users on Win10 try to install it, they see a RED warning about malware.

[image: 1]

You can see that "Publisher" is shown: Open Source Developer, Andrei Ovsiankin. This is me.

I understand that smartscreen counts software reputations, but why the warning is red? It is usually blue and not so scary.

Comment: Having a publisher is one thing, but are you known as a safe publisher to the computer? Also, is your installer digitally signed to show you are legitimate? These are the questions you need to answer so the computer knows you are trying to be safe and not a virus.

Comment: Installer is a signed MSI file/ What do you mean under "is your installer digitally signed to show you are legitimate". It is sighned, but of course, i'm not known to Microsoft. Such installers are usually show a blue message, but in this case it is red and it scares users. The question is "Why it is read instead of blue? Is it normal?"

Comment: Is your signing cert issued by a verified CA or is it just a self signed cert? Maybe smart screen is red when it doesn't 'know you' and the certificate is not issued by a default trusted CA.

Comment: It is issued by CA named Certum http://www.certum.eu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of SmartScreen Application Reputation depends on whether an application is unsigned, OV signed, or EV signed:

- Each unsigned application needs to build reputation individually, once for each unique binary.
- The first application signed with a standard organization-validated code signing certificate needs to build reputation in the same manner. But SmartScreen allows reputation to leak from one application to others signed with the same certificate, allowing an application to shed its warning more quickly. The [inexpensive certificate that Certum offers to some free software developers](https://en.sklep.certum.pl/data-safety/code-signing-certificates/open-source-code-signing.html) likely falls in this category.
- A more expensive Extended Validation (EV) certificate comes with instant reputation, but it may not be available to individual developers of free software or freeware.